# Laravel in many to many relationship using where clause in both tables not filtering data

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, many-to-many

This question might looks stupid, but I'm really stack in this.

I have two tables `employees` and `posts` there relationship defined as below.

```
employee model

class Employee extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class)->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

post model

class Post extends Model
{
    public function employees(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Employee::class)->withPivot('status')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

and this is the pivot table `employee_post`

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employee_post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('employee_id');
            $table->string('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in the controller I want to select a post by it's id and select employee where `user_id` in employee table is the id of loged-in user, but my query fetch one employee if post id is 1 two employees if id is 2 and three employees if post id is 3. I'm really confused.

```
    public function show($id){
        
        $post = Post::whereId($id)
        ->whereHas('employees', function($q){
            $q->where('user_id',Auth::id());
        })->with('employees','address', 'service', 'options','images')
        ->first();
        return response()->json($post);
    }
```

There are the screenshots.

Post id=1
[image]

Post id=2
[image]

Post id=3
[image]
Post id=2

I want to fetch a post with only one related employee.

any eloquent or query builder solution please?

Update:
This is employee migration

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->string('business_abn')->nullable();
            $table->string('business_details')->nullable();
            $table->string('stripe_customer_id')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id');
            $table->double('balance')->nullable();
            $table->date('balance_updated_at')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('is_balance_auto_renew')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and this is post migration

```
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('note')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('employee_id');//id of who posted
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('address_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('service_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('number_of_accepted')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

in post table I have `employee_id`, this is a one to many relationship, which one employee can post many post. there shouldn't be any confusion.

for clearance:
one employee post, other employees receive this post, here; posts table has two relations with employees one as poster which is one-to-many and receiver which is many-to-many.

There is no problem in one-to-many relations.

Comment: which one of the employees do you want for each Post?

Comment: Can you post your employees table pleases? Just wanting to check if this line is correct $q->where('user_id',Auth::id());

Comment: The employee currently loged in, I have added employees and posts table please see.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set conditions for emloyees in with method, otherwise all relevant employees will be retrieved.

Use withWhereHas:

```
 public function show($id){
        $post = Post::whereId($id)
        ->withWhereHas('employees', function($q){
            $q->where('user_id',Auth::id()); 
        })->with('address', 'service', 'options','images')
        ->first();
        return response()->json($post);
    }
```

Or use With:

```
public function show($id){
    $post = Post::whereId($id)
        ->with(['employees' => function($q){
            $q->where('user_id',Auth::id());
        }])->with('address', 'service', 'options','images')
        ->first();
    return response()->json($post);
}
```

The difference is:

For withWhereHas method, **null** will be returned if there is no relevant employees

For with method, **a post instance with employees is empty** will be returned if there is no relevant employees

Comment: hi Khang, the first query gives this error. "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder::withWhereHas()"     and the second give this error "mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given".

Comment: I modified the second way, it should be an associated array.

Comment: You are welcome. Btw, you can merge 2 with methods into one

Comment: Dear Khang, your solution helped me alot.  if I use pivot instead of user_id, it return this error. `
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pivot.status' in 'where clause' ` how can I filter by pivot instead of user_id in your query.

Comment: For pivot, try using methods listed in: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#filtering-queries-via-intermediate-table-columns